# match repeated blocks separated by ~

Tags: java, regex, match

To match the following text:

text : `SS~B66\88~PRELIMINARY PAGES\M01~HEADING PAGES`

It has this format:`<code1>~<description1>\<code2>~<description2>\<code3>~<description3>....<codeN>~<descriptionN>`

I used this regex: `[A-Z0-9 ]+~[A-Z0-9 ]+(?:\\[A-Z0-9 ]+~[A-Z0-9 ]+)+`

So:

**case 1**. SS~B66\88~PRELIMINARY PAGES\M01~HEADING PAGES `(Match: OK)`

**case 2**. SS~B66\88~PRELIMINARY PAGES~HEADING PAGES `(No Match: OK because I removed the code 'M01')`

**case 3**. SS~B66~PRELIMINARY PAGES\M01~HEADING PAGES `(No Match: OK because I removed the code '88')`

More examples:

- SS~B66\88~MEKLKE\M01~MOIIE
- B~A310\0~PRELIM@INARY\00-00~HEADING

My problem is that `<code>` and `<description>` can accept  any type of characters, so when I replaced my regex with:

My new regex `.+~.+(?:\\.+~.+)+` , but it can match **case 2** and **case 3**.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I know I already tried .+? but it stops at the first matched character

Comment: You state that the example data has `<code>~<description>` but this has 3 parts `SS~B66\88~PRELIMINARY`, this has 2 parts `PAGES\M01~HEADING` and there is a separate word at the end. You can make it quite specific, but is that what you are after? https://regex101.com/r/P7mjjG/1 Can you give an example of a string that contains all kinds of characters that should still match vs the ones that should not match?

Comment: Only one bloc after each separation by "\" : example `<code>~<description> \ <code>~<description> \ <code>~<description>`

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You can use `^[^~]+~[^\\]+(?:\\[^~]+~[^\\]+)+$`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/btJKYr/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `[A-Z0-9 ]` which would not match all the allowed chars,  or `.+` which would match too much, you can use a negated character class `[^~\\]` matching any char except `\` and `~` to set the boundaries for the matched parts.

```
^[^~]+~[^~\\]+(?:\\[^~]+~[^~\\]+)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^~]+~` Match any char other than `~`, then match `~`
- `[^~\\]+` Repeat matching 1+ times any char other than `~ and` `
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\\[^~]+~[^~\\]+` Match `\` and a  `~` between other chars than `~` before and `~` `\` after
- `)+` Close the group and repeat 1 or more times to match at least a `\`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oAKsAv/1) <sup>(The demo contains `\n` to not cross the newlines in the example data)</sup>

Comment: Thank you it works with a small modification : `^[^\\~]+~[^~\\]+(?:\\[^\\~]+~[^~\\]+)+$` to not match B~A310\0~PRELIMINARY PAGES\\\\00-00~HEADING PAGES for example

Comment: @NourAtfaoui That seems to work for the added use case, excluding the backslashes in all the negated character classes. https://regex101.com/r/67gQxi/1